# fetch: Reject promise with JSON error object

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have an HTTP API that returns JSON data both on success and on failure.

An example failure would look like this:

```
~ ◆ http get http://localhost:5000/api/isbn/2266202022 
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Length: 171
Content-Type: application/json
Server: TornadoServer/4.0

{
    "message": "There was an issue with at least some of the supplied values.", 
    "payload": {
        "isbn": "Could not find match for ISBN."
    }, 
    "type": "validation"
}
```

What I want to achieve in my JavaScript code is something like this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => {
     if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
       return resp.json();
     } else {
       // This does not work, since the Promise returned by `json()` is never fulfilled
       return Promise.reject(resp.json());
     }
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     // Do something with the error object
   }
```

Comment: You mean `json` method returns a `Promise`?

Comment: Yes, as per the `fetch` spec from the working group: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body

Answer (score 104, accepted):

> ```
>  // This does not work, since the Promise returned by `json()` is never fulfilled
> return Promise.reject(resp.json());
> ```

Well, the `resp.json` promise *will* be fulfilled, only `Promise.reject` doesn't wait for it and immediately rejects *with a promise*.

I'll assume that you rather want to do the following:

```
fetch(url).then((resp) => {
  let json = resp.json(); // there's always a body
  if (resp.status >= 200 && resp.status < 300) {
    return json;
  } else {
    return json.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise));
  }
})
```

(or, written explicitly)

```
    return json.then(err => {throw err;});
```

Comment: Thanks, that (almost) did work! I had to wrap Promise.reject in an anonymous function or I'd get an `undefined is not a function` error, but with that small change it works :-)

Comment: Uh, are you lazy-loading a Promise shim? The native `Promise.reject` should never be `undefined`.

Comment: The shim is loaded on application startup, so it shouldn't be lazy-loaded. I can access `Promise.reject` just fine from the debugger, too. Here's the full trace: `TypeError: undefined is not a function {stack: "TypeError: undefined is not a function↵    at reject (native)", message: "undefined is not a function"}`

Comment: At reject? Ah, it needs to be `.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise))`.

Comment: I would seem that `json.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise))` is equivalent to `Promise.reject(json)`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @torazaburo: No, `json` is a promise here, and we don't want to reject with the promise but with its result value.

Comment: There is no body if you get a '204 No Content' response ;)

Comment: @CpILL: But still an empty one, isn't there?

Comment: @Bergi what if my response has no body? resp.json() will throw an error. How to handle that?

Comment: @ShabbirEssaji Then move the `resp.json()` call in the `else` part (assuming your errors have bodies) and in the `if` block return a success value. Alternatively use `resp.text()` (which should return an empty string?) or add an `if (resp.headers.get('Content-Length') > 0)` check.

Answer (score 42):

Here's a somewhat cleaner approach that relies on [`response.ok`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-ok) and makes use of the underlying JSON data instead of the `Promise` returned by `.json()`.

```js
function myFetchWrapper(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json().then(json => {
      return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
    });
  });
}

// This should trigger the .then() with the JSON response,
// since the response is an HTTP 200.
myFetchWrapper('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Brooklyn,NY').then(console.log.bind(console));

// This should trigger the .catch() with the JSON response,
// since the response is an HTTP 400.
myFetchWrapper('https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search').catch(console.warn.bind(console));
```

Comment: Ah, `.ok` looks interesting. Yet I don't see usage of "the underlying JSON data" is cleaner. After all, you could simplify this to `fetch(url).then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : response.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err)))`

Comment: I meant that instead of `let json = resp.json();` where `json` is a `Promise`, it could be simpler to resolve the `Promise` first and then make use of the data its resolved with. Either approach works.

Comment: Was trying to reject the nested promise but wasn't quite sure how. Turns out it's simply a call to the static "reject" method. A far better answer than the accepted one in my view.

Answer (score 12):

The solution above from [Jeff Posnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385997/jeff-posnick) is my favourite way of doing it, but the nesting is pretty ugly.

With the newer **async/await** syntax we can do it in a more synchronous looking way, without the ugly nesting that can quickly become confusing.

```
async function myFetchWrapper(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const json = await response.json();
  return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
}
```

This works because, [an async function always returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value) and once we have the JSON we can then decide how to return it based on the response status (using [response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok)).

You would error handle the same way as you would in Jeff's answer, however you could also use try/catch, an [error handling higher order function](https://wesbos.github.io/Async-Await-Talk/#59), or with some modification to prevent the promise rejecting you can use my favourite technique that ensures [error handling is enforced as part of the developer experience](https://twitter.com/scotups/status/1252350125525159936).

```
const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Brooklyn,NY'

// Example with Promises
myFetchWrapper(url)
  .then((res) => ...)
  .catch((err) => ...);

// Example with try/catch (presuming wrapped in an async function)
try {
  const data = await myFetchWrapper(url);
  ...
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error(err.message);
}
```

Also worth reading [MDN - Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful) for why we have to do this, essentially a fetch request only rejects with network errors, getting a 404 is not a network error.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any):

```
function fetchAndDecode(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(response => {
    if(!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    } else {
      return response.blob();
    }
  })
}

let coffee = fetchAndDecode('coffee.jpg');
let tea = fetchAndDecode('tea.jpg');

Promise.any([coffee, tea]).then(value => {
  let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(value);
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = objectURL;
  document.body.appendChild(image);
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(e.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this option can be valid

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    fetch(url)
    .then(async (response) => {
        const data = await response.json();
        return { statusCode: response.status, body: data };
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
            resolve(response.body);
        } else {
            reject(response.body);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).