# Cleanest way to handle custom errors with fetch & ES6 promise

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am trying to intelligently handle the success/error responses from our API using fetch & ES6 promises.

Here is how I need to handle response statuses:

```
204: has no json response, but need to treat as success
406: should redirect to sign in
422: has json for error message
< 400 (but not 204): success, will have json
>= 400 (but not 422): error, will not have json
```

So, I am struggling with how to write this cleanly.

I have some less than stellar code working right now that looks like this:

```
fetch()
  .then(response => checkStatus(response))
  .then(parseJSON)                           //will throw for the 204
  .then(data => notify('success', someMsg))
  .catch(error => checkErrorStatus(error))
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(data => notify('error', dataForMsg)
  .catch(error => notify('error', someGenericErrorMsg)
```

But it seems pretty weird to use catch twice and I don't know how to deal with that 204 just yet.

Also, just to clarify `checkStatus` and `checkErrorStatus` do a similar thing:

```
export function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
  } else {
    let error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}

function checkErrorStatus(error) {
  if(error.response.status === 422) {
    return error.response
  } else {
    let error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}
```

Any suggestions for cleaning this up?

Comment: oh just something simple like this: export function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json()
}

Comment: For the `422` case see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29473426/1048572)

Comment: What does "*< 400 (but not 422)*" mean?

Comment: Well, a response from the server with a status of 422 will have some JSON that has things like validation error messages that I use to display in an error notification. But all other 400's won't have that json. They will need to be treated differently.

Comment: I meant that it's supposed to be "*< 400: success*" and "*>= 400 (but not 422): error, no json*"

Comment: and yes thanks for clarifying, tired brain here...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you can write it out pretty easily:

```
fetch(…).then(response => {
    if (response.ok)
        return response[response.status == 204 ? "text" : "json"]();
    if (response.status == 422)
        return response.json().then(err => { throw err; });
    if (response.status == 406)
        var error = new AuthentificationError(response.statusText); // or whatever
    else
        var error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error;
})
```

Comment: Yeah, this is nice, you thought of at least two things in there that might not have occurred to me. And now that I look at this, this problem would serve as a good challenge in an interview!

Comment: Just a little note, my webpack setup complained about `throw err` not being in curly brackets, but other than that your solution crushed it.

Comment: @jasongonzales: Thanks - now that you mention it, my mental syntax parser sounds the alarm as well :-)

Comment: Just FYI, you can't use `let` in a single-line `if` block. You'd need to declare `let error` further up the scope, or use...`var` :)

Comment: @RGraham: Good catch, thanks. I just learned that it's even a syntax error, as `let` declarations are no statements, they are statementlistitems.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Bergi's solution, you might consider mechanising the handling of responses with a fairly simple `ResponseHandler()` object;

```
function ResponseHandler() {
    this.handlers = [];
    this.handlers[0] = function() {}; // a "do nothing" default handler
}
ResponseHandler.prototype.add = function(code, handler) {
    this.handlers[code] = handler;
};
ResponseHandler.prototype.handle = function(response) {
    var h = this.handlers,
        s = response.status,
        series = Math.floor(s / 100) * 100; // 100, 200, 300 etc
    (h[s] || h[series] || h[0])(response); // sniff down the line for a specific/series/default handler, then execute it.
};
```

In use :

```
// create an instance of ResponseHandler() and add some handlers :
var responseHandler = new ResponseHandler();
responseHandler.add(204, function(response) {...}); // specific handler
responseHandler.add(422, function(response) {...}); // specific handler
responseHandler.add(406, function(response) {...}); // specific handler
responseHandler.add(200, function(response) {...}); // 200 series default handler
responseHandler.add(400, function(response) {...}); // 400 series default handler
responseHandler.add(0, function(response) {...}); // your overall default handler

// then :
fetch(…).then(response => { responseHandler.handle(response); });
```

You would lose the efficiencies of a hard coded solution such as Bergi's, but potentially benefit from improved manageability and reusability.