# Fetch api - getting json body in both then and catch blocks for separate status codes

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am using fetch api for fetching an URL that might return:

> Response : status = 200, json body = {'user': 'abc', 'id': 1}

or

> Response : status = 400 , json body = {'reason': 'some reason'}

or

> Response : status = 400 , json body = {'reason': 'some other reason'}

I want to make a separate function `request()` that I use from various parts of my code as follows:

```
    request('http://api.example.com/').then(
        // status 200 comes here
        data => // do something with data.id, data.user
    ).catch(
        // status 400, 500 comes here
        error =>  // here error.reason will give me further info, i also want to know whether status was 400 or 500 etc
    )
```

I am unable to do the split between 200 and 400,500 (i have tried by throwing an error). When I throw an error, I am finding it hard to still extract the JSON body (to use for error.reason).

My current code is as follows:

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';

/**
 * Requests a URL, returning a promise
 */
export default function request(url, options={}) {

    console.log('sending api request, url = ' + url)

    return fetch(url, options)
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then((data) => ({data}))
        .catch((err) => ({err}));
}


function checkStatus(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response;
    }

    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
}



function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json();   // json() is a promise itself
}
```

I have tried to solve this by doing as follows, by inverting the order of `.then()` calls, but does not work

```
export default function request(url, options) {
    return fetch(url, options)
        .then(parseJSON)        // note that now first calling parseJSON to get not just JSON but also status. 
        .then(checkStatus)      // i.e. Inverted order of the two functions from before

        .then((data) => ({data}))
        .catch((err) => ({err}));
}

function checkStatus({data, status}) {

    if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
        return data;
    }
    else {
        // const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        const error = new Error("Something went wrong");
        // error.response = response;
        error.data = data;

        throw error;
    }

}

function parseJSON(response) {
    let jsonBody

    response.json().then(json => {
        jsonBody = json                 // this does not help, i thought it will make jsonBody fill up, but seems its in a diff thread
    })              

    return {
        data: jsonBody,
        status: response.status     // my aim is to send a whole dict with status and data to send it to checkStatus, but this does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: The error comes is in the second callback in .then ->  `request('http://api.example.com/').then( function(data){ //success call back, i.e 200 }, function(  jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // error call back. Check the status code here } );`

Comment: `this does not help` - the issue with that code is that Promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous (the code assumes they do)

Comment: duplicate of [Cleanest way to handle custom errors with fetch & ES6 promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33907465/1048572) or [fetch: Reject promise with JSON error object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29473426/1048572)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`response.json()` returns an asynchronous result. You are not returning the object at `parseJSON` from within `.then()` chained to `response.json()`. To correct that issue you can return `response.json()` promise at `parseJSON` call and return object containing `data` and `status` from within `.then()` chained to `response.json()`

```
function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json().then(json => {
          return {
                   data: json,
                   status: response.status  
                 }
    })         
}
```

Comment: you can actually shorten that functions body to `return response.json().then(json => ({ data: json, status: response.status }));`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, did not want to further complicate matters at Answer

Comment: looks like the OP is familiar enough with arrow functions to even do `var parseJSON = response => response.json().then(json => ({ data: json, status: response.status }));`

Answer (score 0):

Here's slightly different approach: With a one-liner I create a response-like promise with ok, status and json-as-object (not a promise), then I decide what to do with this object. Generally I reject with response if response.ok is false, otherwise I resolve with only the json-data. Network errors/json-parse-errors are rejected as usual.

```
fetch(url, options)
    .then(r => r.json().then(json => ({ok: r.ok, status: r.status, json})))
    .then( r => r.ok ? r.json: Promise.reject(r))
```

Comment: As far as I know using the spread operator with response doesn't work but results in undefined. So your es6 example is wrong. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @webwelten: You're right, and I don't know why I wrote that. I believe it worked for me when I wrote it (I usually test code before I post). However that code (now abondoned) went through a compile step (babel and/or typescript, if I remember correctly) to old-style JS, so perhaps that's the reason. I will remove that line from the answer.