# Get status and data from request api by fetch in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I try extract data and status request from request in react native, when utilize this code

```
function postUser(FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, Password) {
    let data = {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        mode: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: Email,
            password: Password,
            first_name: FirstName,
            last_name: LastName,
            phone: Phone
        })
    }
    return fetch(URLPostUser, data)
        .then(response => response.json())
}
```

in this result don't had status.

when change the return of function, i try get status, but in this case don't have access to data

```
function postUser(FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, Password) {
    let data = {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        mode: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: Email,
            password: Password,
            first_name: FirstName,
            last_name: LastName,
            phone: Phone
        })
    }
    return fetch(URLPostUser, data)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
return fetch(URLPostUser, data)
    .then(response => ({ response, json: response.json()}))
```

Now the promised object is

```
{
    response: // the response object
    json: // the parsed JSON
}
```

Or if you don't want the whole response

```
return fetch(URLPostUser, data)
    .then(response => ({ status: response.status, json: response.json()}))
```

The resulting promise is of the object

```
{
    status: // the response object
    json: // the parsed JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39339648/8533250

Those link was helpful for me.
Because previously answer return

`{ status: 200, json: Promise})`