# Fetch Result Return with status code and json data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a fetch API call that calls API back end and in return, I will get the response object with status code. What I am trying to do is base on return, I wanted to return the JSON response with status code. so that other part of the javascript can manipulate base on status code. My fetch function is as follow.

I have tried with as follow below, but it returns as a given screenshot. It gives me promise value which I didn't want to get. 
[image]

```
export const createUser = ( posts ) => {
    const apiRoute= "/api/register";
    return window.fetch(`${apiRoute}`, {
       "headers": headers,
       method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify(posts)
    }).then(response => ({
        'status' : response.status,
        'data'   : response.json()
    }))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error))
        ;

}
```

I know that it might be the duplicate from this post ([Fetch api - getting json body in both then and catch blocks for separate status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339524/fetch-api-getting-json-body-in-both-then-and-catch-blocks-for-separate-status)), but I do not want my data to return as a promise. Instead, I wanted to return fully constructed well form JSON data.

Something like this.

```
{status: 400, data: {id:1,name:Hello World}}
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"It gives me promise value"*

That's right, as per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

You need to resolve that promise before resolving the outer promise.

For example

```js
.then(response => {
  return response.json().then(data => ({
    status: response.status,
    data
  }))
})
```

Alternatively, use an `async` function

```js
export const createUser = async ( posts ) => {
  const apiRoute= "/api/register";
  try {
    const response = await window.fetch(apiRoute, {
      headers,
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(posts)
    })
    return {
      status: response.status,
      data: await response.json()
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error: ', error)
    throw error
  }
}
```