# How to get an error response body from fetch in the catch block?

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

In order to handle statuscodes which are not `200` I used a `StatusCodeHandler` which throws a extended `Error` which I then can use in the `catch` block of the returned promise.

```js
class RequestError extends Error {
  response: Response;

  constructor(message: string, response: Response) {
    super(message);
    this.response = response;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

const StatusCodeHandler = (response: Response) => {
  if (response.ok) return response;
  const error = new RequestError(response.statusText, response);
  throw error;
};

export default StatusCodeHandler;
```

Then I have my request method:

```js
export default function someRestCall(somedata: string, someOtherdata: string) {

  // code omitted

  return fetch(someurl)
    .then(StatusCodeHandler)
    .then(respone => {
      return respone;
    }); // Do something with the error
}
```

And in the component I use it like this (here on a button):

```js
<Button
       title="Register"
            onPress={() => {
              someResCall(data1, data2)
                .then(() => {
                  this.success();
                })
                .catch((err)=> {
                  Alert.alert('something went wrong');
                  this.noSuccess();
                });
            }}
          />
```

So far so good. However the requirements have changed and I get an error object back with informations which I have to handle in my component. But I have no idea how to get to this information in the catch block.
 When I log`err.response` it does not contain this information.

Comment: Can you console.log(err) and see what is it ?

Comment: No, I get an error when I do ``console.log(err)`` but as I wrote when I do ``console.log(err.response)`` I get the response but I have no idea how to get to the error body.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was right in front of me but I could not see it...

In the `catch` block I just have to return `err.response.json()` and handle the result in another `then()` block like that:

```js
<Button
       title="Register"
            onPress={() => {
              someResCall(data1, data2)
                .then(() => {
                  this.success();
                })
                .catch((err)=> err.response.json())
                .then(errJson=>{
                // handle error message here
                console.log(errJson) };
            }}
          />
```

I am just not sure if this is a good practise todo but it works

Comment: Well apparently this is NOT a good way to do it since the last ``then`` block is also called when there is no error. So what todo?

Comment: Is there a way to find what happended in PHP Backend when a 'fetch' API tells the response.json() is failed with the message 'Unexpected Token ...'? Thanks for your answer

Comment: As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39339648/2844467, instead of chaining `then` after the `catch` block, you can chain `then` after `err.response.json()`. That is, `.catch(err => err.response.json().then(json => {// handle json here});`

Comment: Or, `async` / `await` pair could help too like
    `.catch(async err => { const errJson = await err.json(); // and handle errorJson after this line })`