# how to parse json after exception handling promise with isomorphic-fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-promise

During implementing login feature with React, Redux, isomorphic-fetch, ES6 Babel.

***Questions***

I do not know how to properly combine promises after the checkstatus promise in order to get parsed JSON data from my server.
what am I doing wrong here?

also, do I need to replace `isomorphic-fetch` package with other more convenient one?
any suggestion for other package is welcome!

**loginAction.js**

```
import * as API from '../middleware/api';
import * as ActionTypes from '../actionTypes/authActionTypes';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

function encodeCredentials(id, pwd) {
  return btoa(`${id}{GS}${pwd}`);
}

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    response;
  } else {
    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}

export function loginFailure(error) {
  return { error, type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE };
}

export function loginSuccess(response) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ response, type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS });
  };
}

export function loginRequest(id, pwd) {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST,
    command: 'login',
    lang: 'en',
    str: encodeCredentials(id, pwd),
    ip: '',
    device_id: '',
    install_ver: '',
  };
}


export function login(id, pwd) {
  const credentials = loginRequest(id, pwd);

  return dispatch => {
    fetch(`${API.ROOT_PATH}${API.END_POINT.LOGIN}`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    })
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(`parsed data ${data}`);
      dispatch(loginSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(`request failed ${error}`);
    });
  };

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my projects usually, I have a helper function `fetchJSON` that does all utility logic, such as JSON parsing and status check.

Here it is:

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

function checkStatus(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    return response;
  } else {
    const error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}

export default function enhancedFetch(url, options) {
  options.headers = Object.assign({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }, options.headers);
  if(typeof options.body !== 'string') {
    options.body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
  }
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON);
}
```

Then you can use it in actions:

```
import fetchJSON from '../utils/fetchJSON'; // this is the enhanced method from utilities

export function login(id, pwd) {
    const credentials = loginRequest(id, pwd);

    return dispatch => {
       fetchJSON(`${API.ROOT_PATH}${API.END_POINT.LOGIN}`, {
           method: 'post',
           body: credentials
       }).then(data => {
           console.log(`parsed data ${data}`);
           dispatch(loginSuccess(data));
       }).catch(error => {
           console.log(`request failed ${error}`);
       });
   };
}
```

It helps you to keep actions code clean from some boilerplate code. In big projects with tons of similar `fetch` calls it is a really must-have thing.

Comment: Oh wow! I really appreciate that. This is really useful best practices i have ever seen so far!

Comment: Object assign modifying the original object spit a warning, so i passed {} for the first argument.

Comment: I see that on error you set error.response = response What if an API server sends an Error object according to the JSON API specification? http://jsonapi.org/format/#error-objects How would you parse the error object then?

Comment: @Biruk you can find a solution in related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473426/fetch-reject-promise-with-json-error-object

Comment: @Biruk also, if you have to deal with JSON API in the typical way, you may use special library for it, for example https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

Comment: @just-boris I use isomorphic-fetch but the related question is very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice code snippet. Just one comment, Object.assign is not supported on IE, so that code will break on Windows's users. Instead use some polyfill to make a copy without using Object.assign like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it right, you just forgot `return` in `checkstatus`; you should return the `response` such that the next promise in the chain can consume it.

Also, it seems that `checkstatus` is synchronous operation, so it's no need to chain it by `.then` (although, it's OK if you like it that way), you can write:

```
fetch(...)
.then(response=>{
   checkStatus(response)
   return response.json()
})
.then(data=>{
   dispatch(loginSuccess(data))
})
.catch(...)
```

I see no reason to get rid of `isomorphic-fetch` for now - it seems that it does its job.

Comment: No, `response.json()` is async operation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json