# Redux, Fetch, How to catch json()

Tags: javascript, promise, redux, fetch-api, redux-thunk

I using a Web API that will return a `400` for an invalid login attempt. When the user attempts to login with the wrong credentials, the api will return something like:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": "Invalid credentials. Please try again".
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is: When the response is 400, it should return the json and dispatch it using `dispatch(loginUserFailure(error))`. Of course, in case of success, it should `dispatch(loginUserSuccess(json))`. In my case, it would be very handy if the `.then(json => {...}` had access to the response object but obviously this isn't possible.

Any ideas on a workaround this or any suggestions on what to look would be great!

```
export function loginUser(username, password) {

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
  };

  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return fetch('/api/accounts/login/', options)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        // Check the response status here and dispatch respectively
        // if (response.status !== 400) {
        //   dispatch(loginUserFailure(error));
        // }
        dispatch(loginUserSuccess(json));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(loginUserFailure(error));
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Why not just use `if (response.status !== 400) return response.json().then(loginUserSuccess).then(dispatch)`?

Comment: @Bergi Would you say that something like this is the right approach? http://pastebin.com/C2Bn65hd

Comment: Yes, exactly, though you might want to [throw the json as an error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29475662/1048572) to avoid the duplication of `dispatch(loginUserFailure(…))`

Comment: That's it! With your suggestion, I think it is exactly what I need. If you want to copy-paste the answer, feel free to get it from the updated pastebin http://pastebin.com/pGQFCht0 @Bergi Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can **`reject` promises manually**, which comes in handy if an invalid response code is returned. This will then be handled by the `catch` callback.

[The MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) has more info on `Promise.reject()`.

This example shows how it could be done:

```
function status(response) {  
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {  
    return Promise.resolve(response)  
  } else {  
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))  
  }  
}

function json(response) {  
  return response.json()  
}

fetch('users.json')  
  .then(status)  
  .then(json)  
  .then(function(data) {  
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);  
  }).catch(function(error) {  
    console.log('Request failed', error);  
  });
```

[Source, section *Chaining Promises*](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en)

Comment: Also the `Fetch.response` object has an `ok` property that can help you define whether or not you reject it.

Answer (score 1):

Using window.fetch API seems very low-level for you, because it is designed to work with any type of response, but you need only JSON.

Consider use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), or another library, which takes care about JSON--parsing for you.