# How to capture the json text inside fetch's then()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch-api

This how I call `fetch`

```
fetchOpts = {...}
return fetch(url, fetchOpts)
    .then(checkStatus)
```

The url I call will always return a json data, even in the  error condition:

```
{error_message:"Encountered issue with update"
status:"error",
status_code:400}
```

I would like to get hold of the `error_message` field value and pass to the `Error` constructor.

Inside checkStatus, it handles exception this way:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  let error = null;

  if (!response.headers.get('Content-Type').includes('application/json')) {
    error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }

  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }

  if (response.ok) {
    return response;
  }
  const jsonData = response.json() ; // <- `jsonData` is a promise
  error = new Error(/* How to extract error_message from json data? */);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
}
```

I have checked this question already but it does not really address my need [fetch: Reject promise with JSON error object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473426/fetch-reject-promise-with-json-error-object). Also the accepted answer seems, based on the comments, not to resolve OP's question entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the problem, but the `error_message` member is exposed as a property of the data object the promise returns, right? So it seems like you could just do this:

```javascript
response.json()
.then(jsonData => {
  if (jsonData.error_message) {
    error = new Error(jsonData.error_message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your last bit of code to

```
return response.json().then(json => {
    error = new Error(json.error_message);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
}
```

That should do what you want