# Is using async/await the only way to receive a resolved promise from Promise.reject()?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code below. What i want to do is handle the network error case and the returned HTTP server error cases separately.

```
fetch("$imageUploadUrl", {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "same-origin",
          cache: "no-store",
          credentials: "same-origin",
          redirect: "error",
          referrer: "origin",
          body: formData
      }).catch(function(error) {
        failure("There was an error while uploading the image");
      }).then(function(response) {
          if (response.ok){
            return Promise.resolve(response.json());
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(response.text())
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        success(result.location);
      }).catch(function(errorText) {
          return failure (errorText);
      })
```

However, unlike `Promise.resolve()`, `Promise.reject()` does not wait to resolve the promise from `response.text()` before returning it. I have managed to receive a resolved promise by adding async/await like that:

```
fetch("$imageUploadUrl", {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "same-origin",
          cache: "no-store",
          credentials: "same-origin",
          redirect: "error",
          referrer: "origin",
          body: formData
      }).catch(function(error) {
        failure("There was an error while uploading the image");
      }).then(async function(response) {
          if (response.ok){
            return Promise.resolve(response.json());
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(await response.text())
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        success(result.location);
      }).catch(function(errorText) {
          failure(errorText);
      });
```

Is this the only way to reach my goal?

I have also tried doing this:

```
fetch("$imageUploadUrl", {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "same-origin",
          cache: "no-store",
          credentials: "same-origin",
          redirect: "error",
          referrer: "origin",
          body: formData
      }).catch(function(error) {
        failure("There was an error while uploading the image");
      }).then(function(response) {
          if (response.ok){
            return Promise.resolve(response.json());
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(response.text())
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        success(result.location);
      }).catch(function(textPromise) {
          return textPromise;
      }).then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
      })
```

But the final then with the `console.log` is called always, even when i call `Promise.resolve()` in the code above it, as it was attached on the promise from fetch function itself. Do you know why this happens.

Comment: BTW, there is no point in returning `Promise.resolve()` from a promise callback; that's already a promise.

Comment: `fetch().catch(x=>something).then(y=>y===something` If you catch a promise then what you return in the catch is the value for the the next `then`. I don't think the code you posted is possible since the catch doesn't return anything so the next then should throw an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined`

Comment: Also setting redirect is pointless since it is [read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/redirect)

Comment: What are `success` and `failure`? This looks a lot like the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [fetch: Reject promise with JSON error object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29473426/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi success and failure are functions received as callbacks from tinymce: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_handler

Also thanks for the link, it does seem like an my question. I was trying to find out if the different way resolve and reject work are by intent and if there is a way to resolve the inner promise when rejecting.

Comment: @LyubomirParvanov Ah, what a pity that tinymce doesn't support returning a promise. I still would recommend creating a promise, and using the callbacks only in the end of the chain as `….then(success, failure);`. Especially the `.catch(function(error) {
        failure("There was an error while uploading the image");
      })` doesn't work - the chain continues with a fulfilled promise after that.

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for the promise, then reject it:

```
return response.text().then(text => Promise.reject(text));
```

Comment: This won't work. `reject` has to be bound to `Promise` so either `v => Promise.reject(v)` or `Promise.reject.bind(Promise)`

Comment: And what if the response is a JSON?

Comment: @VladislavLadicky apologies for the last comment, it took me a moment to realize you weren't OP. This statement is intended to replace just `return Promise.reject(response.text())` in the question, not the entire response handling.

Comment: @VladislavLadicky: That would use the OP's original, unchanged codepath.

Comment: Ok, so I improved my answer.

Answer (score -2):

And what about this version:

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'same-origin',
  cache: 'no-store',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  referrer: 'origin',
  body: formData
}

async function parseResponse (response) {
  try {
    success(await response.json())
  } catch () {
    failure(await response.text())
  }
}

function parseError (err) {
  failure(`Error uploading file: ${err}`)
}

fetch('$imageUploadUrl', options)
  .then(parseResponse)
  .catch(parseError)
```

Comment: What if the JSON is a string?

Comment: And what if it is not a string? I just hope he know what the fetch is returning and why, under what conditions.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.  He wants to fail as text if `ok` is false, not if the JSON is unparseable.